# javascript double obfuscation

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

**First of all, I know that obfuscation doesn't prevent reverse engineering**; it just makes it harder and longer, which is what I am looking for.

My code uses jquery; it's the only dependency. I'm looking at the google closure compiler and [jscrambler](http://jscrambler.com/) which both seem to be well regarded. What would happen if I first passed my code through the google closure compiler and then through jscrambler?

Will the code still work in every browser/platform like it does now? Does double obfuscation add any complexity to reverse engineer the source?

Comment: @epascarello: No, double obfuscation looks very virus like, who would try that? :D

Comment: look, put the code on jsPerformance or jsFiddle and click 'beauty code' and it will scare you how easy is to understand the code.

Comment: Well, depends on how much obfuscation you need. The Closure Compiler's Advanced Modes does a very good job, but unfortunately it has a lot of restrictions on your code. It has bindings for jQuery though. If you want to use it, your code will need to be reworked a bit to make sure that it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the code still work in every browser/platform like it does now?

Yes, the outer script would execute its inner script which again tells your browser to execute the inner script that is within the inner script. In other words, ou can put an `eval` in an `eval`.

> Does double obfuscation add any complexity to reverse engineer the source?

It wouldn't necessarily add complexity, but it does result in an extra step that needs to be taken to get towards your source. Note how the inner obfuscation that you use is itself obfuscated by the outer obfuscation, so on a single pass the reverse engineer is presented with the obfuscated code of your inner obfuscation but not your actual source code itself.

When I was reverse engineering in the past (to determine if some executable was a virus), I've literally came across a program in C# which in an obfuscated way first unpacks another file, that other file again unpacks yet another DLL file which then gets load and then it actually loads in code from a resource in that DLL file which is finally executed and does some nasty code to connect to some online service.

Bottom line is that this required me quite some more time to get to that obfuscated nasty code.

So yes, double obfuscation could increase the complexity and take it longer to get to your code.

**But, make sure that you aren't introducing performance or maintenance costs as a result.**

And yeah, *eventually everything they have obfuscated access to can be reverse engineered*...

Answer (score 0):

The way obfuscation works is it pretty much just renames variables to "a", "b", "c" and so forth in order to make it less readable. It will also usually remove all formatting of the code, making the entire class only a few lines long from an input of hundreds of lines for instance.

Anyone who really wants to find out what the code is doing, will. This will, as you said, make it more difficult to read and reverse engineer. Unfortunately since you cannot compile javascript you are stuck with it needing to be plain text, so protection isn't much of an option.

I know there are products out there that will allow you to encrypt the script, but the script is still able to be decrypted by just running the script locally. As a result, a little bit of effort will produce the unencrypted script.